# the photo counter went from 23 to 1 after new batteries, why?

Tags: 35mm

I was halfway done with a roll of film but I needed to put new batteries in and as I did the counter went from 23 back to 1. Is the film ruined? double exposure? counting wrong?

Comment: What camera? Did you hear the film rewind?

Comment: Can you provide more detail about the camera make & model.  When you changed the batteries, did this involve opening the back of the camera (some cameras reset the film counter if the back is opened)?